# The same text displaying over and over in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

The textView that I'm currently using in my ListView is being displayed over and over, without changing it's information, but I'm not able to see why, can I get a litte help? Code:

Main code named Principal.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lista;

String[][]datos = {
        {"Mediciones del día"},
        {" "},
        {"Promedios del día"},
};

int [] datosImg = {R.drawable.celeste, R.drawable.rojo, R.drawable.verde};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLista);

    lista.setAdapter(new Adaptador(this, datos, datosImg));
  }
}
```

My adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

Context contexto;
String [][] datos;
int[] datosImg;

    public Adaptador (Context context, String [][] datos,int []imagenes)
{
    this.contexto = context;
    this.datos = datos;
    this.datosImg = imagenes;
    inflater = 
(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);
    TextView titulo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ImageView imagen = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    titulo.setText(datos[0][0]);
    imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);
    /*
    imagen.setTag(i);
    */
    /*
    imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      @Override
              public void onClick(View v){
         Intent visorImagen = new Intent(contexto, VisorImagen.class);
         visorImagen.putExtra("IMG", datosImg[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
         contexto.startActivity(visorImagen);
        }

    });
    */
    return vista;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return datosImg.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

I have been looking for the solution for a really long time, but I haven't found anything online.

Comment: Hi there! I recommend you try debugging the code yourself first, the community won't do it for you. Also it is a skill all good programmers require so you might as well start learning/practicing now! Ask google for debugging tips, there's loads of tutorials out there :)

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution doing that! :)

Comment: Awesome!! If you found the answer you can answer your own question so others with the same problem can see the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!, intead of

```
    titulo.setText(datos[i][0]);
    imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);
```

I wrote:

```
    titulo.setText(datos[0][0]);
    imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);
```

This means that it only shows 1 text, but the other one displays one text, and then goes to the next one. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to give position here, evrytime you set [0][0] will return the same value eveytime, do somthing like this.

```
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);
    TextView titulo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ImageView imagen = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    titulo.setText(datos[i][i]);
    imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);
    /*
    imagen.setTag(i);
    */
    /*
    imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      @Override
              public void onClick(View v){
         Intent visorImagen = new Intent(contexto, VisorImagen.class);
         visorImagen.putExtra("IMG", datosImg[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
         contexto.startActivity(visorImagen);
        }

    });
    */
    return vista;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `datos` an array list like: `ArrayList<String>` and add elements with `yourList.add()`. Then in the adapter set the text to the `TextView` with `titulo.setText(yourList.get(i)`. 
Hope it helps!